# Why every layout xml root node has a version

Tags: layout

Why does the root layout xml node have a version number:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
```

I have searched the source code and cannot find this being used.
Is it a feature that never got implemented? or taken out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vestigial convention which was never implemented. It can be safely ignored/omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I've been wondering the same for a long time, since I worked with Magento 1.0 (some eons ago).
I got to the conclusion that is useless. In my custom modules that have a layout I don't even add the `version` attribute and it works just fine.
Even for the custom themes where I needed to copy one core layout file to my theme an modify it, I removed the `version` attribute and it worked.
I can just assume that someone had an idea about layout versioning (or inheritance) that didn't stick. If it was a feature that was taken out it didn't live to see the first release.
This question was asked on the [magento forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4487/) more than 5 years ago and got no answer

Comment: Not even an answer from Moshe? :)

Comment: That was my main concern also :)