# Breadcrumb definitions for backend pages

Tags: adminhtml, backend, breadcrumbs

I have often seen breadcrumb definitions in controllers that solely manage backend pages, e.g. `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CatalogController.php`

But I have never actually seen a breadcrumb on a backend page.
How come?
Am I missing something? Or am I just blind? :-)

Is there an existing usage anywhere or are the definitions done just in case somebody wants to implement them in the backend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been wondering the same thing for a while.
Here is my conclusion: This is just an other unfinished Magento feature like there are others ([see the `<layout version="0.1.0">` discussion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5240/146) for example).
I base my conclusion on the fact that on in the admin page file (`page.phtml`) there is no line that should show the breadcrumbs. It should be something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```

But the main reason that lead to my conclusion is this method in the breadcrumbs block:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    // TODO - Moved to Beta 2, no breadcrumbs displaying in Beta 1
    // $this->assign('links', $this->_links);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

If you add the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>` in `page.phtml` and uncomment `$this->assign('links', $this->_links);` in the method above you should see the breadcrumbs but not all the pages will have correct breadcrumbs. See for example the add/edit product page. This is because the breadcrumbs are not added in all the pages.
I guess we have to wait for the `Beta 2` as stated by the comment in the code above :).

Comment: I just wonder about it now! ended upon this answer. Wonder ended  :) thanks @Marius

Comment: It's three years later and in the Magento 2 backend I still see references to adding breadcrumbs in controllers, but I have yet to see a single breadcrumb rendered in the admin despite seeing the method included in official Magento 2 books' tutorials. I wonder what the developers are intending by including this feature, but not displaying them by default. What's the point?