# Purpose of Template_Smarty and Template_Zend blocks

Tags: blocks, core

In the folder `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template` there are 3 blocks declared.

- `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade` - I found where this is used. It is used twice for the product view page in order to set some containers.
- `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Smarty` - I found no reference of this. Anyway, this class just extends a core template. Most likely someone wanted to use smarty with magento and abandoned the idea.
- `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Zend` - this has some methods in there. But again I did not find a use of it.

Are the last 2 blocks useful for something? My money is on "unfinished business" but I was wrong before ([with this for example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13598/146)).
Any opinion on this? Anyone used these blocks before?

Comment: I would suggest this should be filed this under "F" for forgotten. Think someone started doing something but then forgot about it.

Comment: I think the same, but I wanted a confirmation from a "higher authority".

Comment: Someone will know someone that knows someone who's sister is the dry cleaner of the developer that did this.

Comment: @DavidManners. I think you should put your comment as an answer. I don't think I'll get a better one. and are you sure the "F" stands for "forgotten" and not something else?

Comment: I was trying to be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I would suggest this will be filed this under "F" for forgotten/failed. It looks like someone started doing something here but then forgot about it or got moved onto something more "important".

There are plenty of other examples of this in Magento, other software and even stuff that I have written so I do not think they will feel lonely.